Does next-intl adds locale path automatically to urls in links?
When I write this:
<Link href="/" locale="es">
    Link
</Link>

I expect the link to go to domain.com/es, not domain.com. Is this expected? This doesn't work for me and I tried everything. How to achieve it? should I add url manipulation logic to <Link> component?

If you're using the Navigation APIs from next-intl, then the link should point to /es, yes. See also the App Router example and have a look at the "Pathnames" link in the navigation.
